# Convergence of a series of double sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_{n,i}:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a double sequence of functions, with $n,i \geq 1$.   If $\|f_{n,i}-f_i\|_{\infty} \to 0 $ as $n \to \infty$, can I conclude that $| \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_{i}(x) - \sum_{i=1}^{n}f_{n,i}(x)| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for all $x \in [a,b]$?

I know this is a very general question, but I am basically wondering if I can enter the limit inside the sum in order to have the series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_{i}(x)$ (where I assume that series converges).

Thank you in advance